# pandas sum each row until zero then retain zero

Tags: pandas, python-3.6

using pandas for the first time and I've provided a smaller version of a data frame i've created like the following:

```
  Date project1 project2 project3    
0 12/10/2017 100 200 300   
1 12/11/2017 0 100 100   
2 12/12/2017 0 0 100
```

I need to do 2 cumsum for each seperate project where it stops at the zero. And another across all of the projects row wise. I keep struggling with either the date or just counting the zeros. Any advice would be appreciates.
So the output would like:

```
 Date project1 project2 project3   
0 12/10/2017 100 200 300       
1 12/11/2017 0 300 400   
2 12/12/2017 0 0 500
```

and

```
Date project1 project2 project3 project_sum   
0 12/10/2017 100 200 300 600   
1 12/11/2017 0 300 400 700   
2 12/12/2017 0 0 500 500
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you 1st question , using `cumsum` and `cumprod`

```
df[['project1','project2','project3']].cumsum().mask(df[['project1','project2','project3']].cumprod().eq(0),0)
Out[86]: 
   project1  project2  project3
0       100       200       300
1         0       300       400
2         0         0       500
```

And then assign it back using `sum(axis=1)`

```
df[['project1','project2','project3']]=df[['project1','project2','project3']].cumsum().mask(df[['project1','project2','project3']].cumprod().eq(0),0)
df['projectSum']=df[['project1','project2','project3']].sum(1)
df
Out[89]: 
         Date  project1  project2  project3  projectSum
0  12/10/2017       100       200       300         600
1  12/11/2017         0       300       400         700
2  12/12/2017         0         0       500         500
```

Comment: i need it to generic not just [project1,project2,etc], ive been looping throught the ids in a dic, beccause it's a dynamic list. or is looping the only way? i.e. for all project*

Comment: @FancyDolphin change df[['project1','project2','project3']] to df.loc[:,df.columns.str.contains('Project') ]

Comment: one thing extra, how do i keep the date in there when making another dataframe

Comment: @FancyDolphin you can set it as index...bysuing df.set_index('Date')